# remove :hover onclick of a button

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button and onlcick of this button i want to remove hover effect of another button.
The code is something like this

```
<input type="button" value="" onclick="removehover();" class="key_box" />
```

and onclick of this button the function removehover should be called.

```
<input type="button" class="wise_box" /> has a property of wise_box:hover which i want to remove.
```

Please help

Comment: Please rewrite the question in a more understandable way..

Answer (score 3):

You must remove wise_box class, as hover effect is applied to all elements with that class when mouse is hovered over them.

In javascript (without jquery) you can edit class attribute through classname property:

```
mybtn.className='';
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WQsbX/)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove one class of many, a simple remove class function is:

```
function removeClass(el, cName) {
  var re = new RegExp('(^|\\s)' + cName + '(\\s|$)');
  el.className = el.className.replace(re, ' ');
}
```

Or if you want to remove all classes, use Goran's answer.